# Represent roles intersections

Tags: data-visualization, subset

I have 11 roles, who defines rights (read, edit, write) on my application. For exemple I have "Inventory" who contains `ressources_read` and `account_all` rights and "User" who contains `account_all`, User is a sub-role of Inventory.

I would like to represent the intersection of roles (ideally a way to see the details of rights), there is too many roles for Venn diagram so I try to find an alternative (heatmap ?)

Comment: Hi, maybe you could try to make an [UpSet diagram](https://caleydo.org/tools/upset/) with your data?

Comment: It is a solution but I would like to put the diagram in a report so I would like to be simpler (maybe it's just not possible with my data), if I do not find any alternative I would use UpSet, thanks !